# How do I stop this download task from running uncontrollably?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, afnetworking

when I use this code, it downloads a unlimited number of times. It will not stop downloading. Does anyone know why this is?

```
 NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
AFURLSessionManager *manager = [[AFURLSessionManager alloc] initWithSessionConfiguration:configuration];

NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://gps.com/2.js"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];

NSURLSessionDownloadTask *downloadTask = [manager downloadTaskWithRequest:request progress:nil destination:^NSURL *(NSURL *targetPath, NSURLResponse *response) {
    NSURL *documentsDirectoryURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomain:NSUserDomainMask appropriateForURL:nil create:NO error:nil];
    // Save this following url to load the file
    return [documentsDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:[response suggestedFilename]];
} completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSURL *filePath, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"File downloaded to: %@", filePath);
}];
[downloadTask resume];
NSString *javaScript = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:URL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error: nil];

[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javaScript];
```

I also have the same problem when using this code:

```
NSString *jsString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"PrivacyView" withExtension:@"js"] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
[_viewWeb stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
NSLog(@"Way out of whack :(");
```

I swear, this is what it looks like when I try to load a javascript file:

```
2017-05-28 00:03:23.724 App[81886:26511084] File downloaded to: file:///Users/App/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/08B20943-5664-415C-87A6-1A6461C6338D/data/Containers/Data/Application/A31516E9-EDE2-4475-84AC-7AD12DE3558F/Documents/App.js
2017-05-28 00:03:25.197 App App[81886:26511084] Logged In?: Yes
2017-05-28 00:03:25.280 App App[81886:26511084] File downloaded to: file:///Users/App/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/08B20943-5664-415C-87A6-1A6461C6338D/data/Containers/Data/Application/A31516E9-EDE2-4475-84AC-7AD12DE3558F/Documents/App.js
2017-05-28 00:03:26.188 App App[81886:26511084] Logged In?: Yes
2017-05-28 00:03:26.267 App App[81886:26511084] File downloaded to: file:///Users/App/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/08B20943-5664-415C-87A6-1A6461C6338D/data/Containers/Data/Application/A31516E9-EDE2-4475-84AC-7AD12DE3558F/Documents/App.js
2017-05-28 00:03:27.570 App App[81886:26511084] Logged In?: Yes
2017-05-28 00:03:27.635 App App[81886:26511084] File downloaded to: file:///Users/App/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/08B20943-5664-415C-87A6-1A6461C6338D/data/Containers/Data/Application/A31516E9-EDE2-4475-84AC-7AD12DE3558F/Documents/App.js
2017-05-28 00:03:28.885 App App[81886:26511084] Logged In?: Yes
2017-05-28 00:03:28.957 App App[81886:26511084] File downloaded to: file:///Users/App/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/08B20943-5664-415C-87A6-1A6461C6338D/data/Containers/Data/Application/A31516E9-EDE2-4475-84AC-7AD12DE3558F/Documents/App.js
2017-05-28 00:03:30.254 App App[81886:26511084] Logged In?: Yes
```

I mean look at how many times its running. It just keeps being called, forever and won't stop.

Comment: Please, add text as text, not as image.

Comment: Set a breakpoint at the first line of this code snippet. How often are you hitting it?

Comment: @Gereon When I add a breakpoint to the first line of the code snippet, the code is not executed.

Comment: @Gereon Maybe it's not being executed because it's in the webViewDidFinishLoad?

Comment: I'm confused. Either this code is never executed, *or* it runs in an infinite loop. Only one can be true...

Comment: @Gereon It runs an infinite loop.

Comment: Then you must be able to set a breakpoint, hit it and from there determine where it's called from. The snippet you've posted does not contain loops or recursive calls, so there's no way to determine what the problem is from that.